# Any way to suggest places to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-checkins

I am developing an android application which has the simple call to check-in feature which will help the students of a university collaborate and see what their friends like/visit.

I am trying to get the specific place of interest by passing the latitude and longitude and getting response as a list of places nearby. Unfortunately, I am not able to find the appropriate location required as it's not registered with facebook as a place(which is understandable as it's a building inside campus).

Is it possible for me to suggest Facebook with specific places which aren't registered on facebook yet?

Comment: No this is part of a project which I am developing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not able to create Places explicitly within the Facebook Graph API, you might try creating a Page for a new Place so you can enable Checkins.  Check out the respective pages on the API documentation for more info: [Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) and [Checkins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/)